# Is there a way to use a string of variable names as input to a function?

Tags: python, function, web3py

What I would like to know is if something like this is possible (Python code below)

```
def my_function(v1, v2):
    return v1+v2

var1 = 1
var2 = 2

vars = "var1,var2"

print(my_function(vars))
```

I know this code will not work because the function requires two arguments, but the reason I would like to know is that I would like to design a function that can change argument length. *args and **kwargs, will not work because the function that I'm calling is already generated. Here is a snippet of my code for context

```
def construct_transaction(value, chain_id, gas, gas_price, **params):

    # amountIn = w3.toWei(0.1, 'ether')   # << These are the variables I would like to 
    # amountOutMin = 1                    # input into the function below
    # path = [token_0_addr, token_1_addr] # "swapExactTokensForTokens"
    # to_addr = my_addr
    # deadline = 1690528847

    for key in params.keys():
        locals()[key] = params[key]       # variables created from params

    nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(w3.toChecksumAddress(my_addr))

    txn = uniswap_v2_router_contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens("amountIn,..,"). \
        buildTransaction({
        'value': 0,
        'chainId': chain_id,
        'gas': gas,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
```

the number of arguments will change depending on the contract and function called. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know if I understand the problem correctly, but do [default arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-default-arguments-in-python) help?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do.  You seem to want to force a change the signature (definition header) of a function from the outside; this isn't possible.  Also, passing in variable names as strings almost always shows a design flaw; you use an iterable of some sort (list, tuple, set, etc.) to pass a group of values under a single variable name.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. What I want to do is send arguments to "construct_transaction" using **params, then send those arguments to the "swapExactTokensForTokens". My goal is to do something like this :
tx = (contract_name).functions.(function_name)(arguments) where contract_name, function_name and arguments can change depending on what gets sent to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your functions in a `dict` to access them by name, and then pass the arguments as `*args`:

```
def execute_fun(my_funs: dict, name: str, args: tuple):
    """
    lookup a function by name from my_funs dict and execute it using the provided args
    """
    return my_funs[name](*args)

def first_fun(a):
    return a + a

def second_fun(a, b):
    return a + b

my_funs = {
    'first_fun': first_fun,
    'second_fun': second_fun
}

execute_fun(my_funs, 'first_fun', (7,)) # 14
execute_fun(my_funs, 'second_fun', (4, 5,)) # 9
```

This *looks* like it might be done better using classes, though, because it will put everything in the correct namespace:

```
class A:

  def first(self, a):
        return a + a

    def second(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name)

    def __call__(self, name, args):
        return self[name](*args)

a = A()
a['first'] # <bound method A.first of <__main__.A object at 0x7fe934541790>>
a('first', (7,)) # 14
a('second', (4, 5,)) # 9
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I was using **kwargs instead of *args. Thanks for the input Jan Christoph Terasa and Prune :). Your code cleared things up for me.